# How can I run a linux command on Windows XAMPP with shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell, cmd, xampp

I would like to run a `sed` command in my php script via `shell_exec` but I get the following error:

```
'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Which is because XAMPP uses the windows shell.
Is there any way I could configure it to use a linux shell?

Comment: Integrate Linux Commands into Windows with PowerShell and the Windows Subsystem for Linux. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/integrate-linux-commands-into-windows-with-powershell-and-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Comment: Thank you so much your link led me to prepend wsl to the script which was a feature I wasnt aware about. I thought it was only to install ubuntu on the windows store but this is  amazing

Comment: @lit I think that could have been posted as an answer.

Comment: @SamuelGfeller do you know you can post an answer to your own question if you think you found a good solution that can help someone else in same situation in future.

Comment: @rineez You are right I'll do.

Comment: Just to clarify: have you installed `sed` anywhere on your local system, like: WSL, cygwin,....? Why not implement the logic behind that `sed` call into your PHP script to stay independent from the host system?

Comment: @NicoHaase that would be cleaner! But I didn't come very far with that. I knew about sed so I just used the console but it would be even better to let PHP do this work. Maybe you could help me with that? I want to append time entries to a markdown file at the end of the line. The relevant lines recongnized with keys.   
First command (remove existing entries):  
`'wsl sed -i "/^'.$key.'/ s/\[[^)]*\]  //" '.$file`  
Second command (add time entries):  
`'wsl sed -i "/^'.$key.'/ s/$/['.$timeUsed.']  /" '.$file`

Comment: @NicoHaase Explanation: 
I want the script to recognize lines in the text that start with `$key` and append at the end of these lines `[` `$timeUsed` `]`. To avoid duplications the `[` `$timeUsed` `]` must be cleared before. Can I change a file content with php so easily?

Comment: Please add all explanation to your question by editing it

Comment: And yes, of course you can edit files with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP shell_exec will try to run the command in the host system.
Therefore you cannot run linux command on windows.

If you really want to try running that in windows and you have windows 10 maybe you can try using wsl ( windows subsystem linux )

Comment: Thank you! Funny thing is that I was testing on Ubuntu so I even used the wsl but couldn't figure out how to do in order for php / xampp to use it. @lit's comment put me on the right track I didnt know this but the solution was prepending `wsl` to the command:
`wsl sed xxx`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @SKos and @lit I came to the solution which is simply install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/integrate-linux-commands-into-windows-with-powershell-and-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/) and then prepend `wsl` to the linux command.

```php
shell_exec('wsl sed "s/abc/def/"')
```